# Collabora (docker) and NextCloud (snap) problem behind proxy on same machine

Tags: apache, docker, ssl, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I decided to post about my situation after many days of troubleshooting. I recently installed NextCloud as snap on Ubuntu 18.04 and everything worked fine. I did the port forwarding and used Let’s Encrypt (from snap commands) to create the certificates for NC.

Then I decided to install Collabora server on the same machine to use the office functionality. I used the official Collaboration guides for installation mentioned [here](https://nextcloud.com/collaboraonline/). However, in this guide, it is assumed that NC is installed manually (not snap). According to guides, I had to install Apache (or any other proxy/web server) to proxy the traffic to whether NC or Collabora.

I think there is a problem with my proxy configuration or something wrong with SSL certificates. When both Apache and snap are running, I can get to Apache page and Collabora should be running, but cannot get to NC page.

I can go to (port 443) link below and get to the page (meaning Collabora is responding?)

> https://collabora.domain.com/loleaflet/dist/admin/admin.html

But when accessing the NC domain, the browser says “Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue” and complain that the certificates are not for that NC domain I am trying to connect but the certificate is for Collabora domain. If I stop the Apache and let Snap running, I can access the NC domain with no issues (except I need to set the ports to 443 and 80 again! Is this problematic?)
My Apache proxy config file (located under /etc/apache2/sites-available/) is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:444>

ServerName nextcloud.domain.com:444
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass        / https://192.168.1.50/
ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.50/

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.domain.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName collabora.domain.com:443

# SSL configuration, you may want to take the easy route instead and use Lets Encrypt!
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/collabora.domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/collabora.domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/collabora.domain.com/privkey.pem
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-$
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

# Encoded slashes need to be allowed
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

# Container uses a unique non-signed certificate
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify None
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off

# keep the host
ProxyPreserveHost On

# static html, js, images, etc. served from loolwsd
# loleaflet is the client part of LibreOffice Online
ProxyPass           /loleaflet https://127.0.0.1:9980/loleaflet retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    /loleaflet https://127.0.0.1:9980/loleaflet

# WOPI discovery URL
ProxyPass           /hosting/discovery https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/discovery$
ProxyPassReverse    /hosting/discovery https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/discovery

# Main websocket
ProxyPassMatch "/lool/(.*)/ws$" wss://127.0.0.1:9980/lool/$1/ws nocanon

# Admin Console websocket
ProxyPass   /lool/adminws wss://127.0.0.1:9980/lool/adminws

# Download as, Fullscreen presentation and Image upload operations
ProxyPass           /lool https://127.0.0.1:9980/lool
ProxyPassReverse    /lool https://127.0.0.1:9980/lool

# Endpoint with information about availability of various features
ProxyPass           /hosting/capabilities https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/capabilities retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    /hosting/capabilities https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/capabilities
</VirtualHost>
```

To be honest, this is first time I am setting up proxy server that do not know how it works. Most of my config file is copied and think that is the issue :) If someone can have a look at it and guide me to the right direction, that would save me lots of headache and time.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same pain for a similar amount of time and eventaully got a simple solution.

The online instructions for docker [here](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/docker/) are correct except that they omit enabling proxy for websockets.

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod ssl
```

The only other change I had to make were to add --cap-add MKNOD to the docker start.

In Nextcloud I then only needed to add https://collab.example.com to the WAPI server address configuration after creating LetsEncrypt certs for my domain (obviously example.com is not my real domain).